# How to change image viewing preferences

Tags: visual-studio-2010, image, visual-studio-2012

When I view the screenshots within results of my Automated Test runs in Visual Studio 2010 the windows appear as follows:

[image]

It's very frustrating having the window split into a normal zoom and zoomed in window by default. Can I change a preference to just display the image normally in a single window?

Alternatively, is there a VS2010 plugin I can use to change how it views pngs?

I have not been able to find anything that suggests it will help me out in the VS2010 Options menu but I am very much willing to admit I've probably overlooked it.

[EDIT] *I am slowly making the switch to VS2012, so this question extends to there too!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This drives me mad as well but I finally found the answer - drag and drop a bmp/png/jpg file into your visual studio project, right click it in the solution explorer and select 'open With' - select MS Paint and click 'Set as Default'. 
Alternatively you can navigate and select whatever your preferred application is for viewing images.

Comment: I can't even begin to say how much this has helped! Even though the VS2012 is a tiny bit better, this still means I can pick something better. Good work!